# Прием сообщений в RabbitMQ, Java

Tags: java, rabbitmq

В туториалах по rabbitmq есть [пример кода](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/java/Recv.java/), описывающего прием сообщений 
. часть кода не совсем понятна:

```
Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
      @Override
      public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
          throws IOException {
        String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
      }
    };
```

1. не совсем понятно, что в скобках. у нас вроде создается объект `consumer`, и тут идет в фигурных скобках тело...не понимаю тело чего. это реализация конструктора?
2. можно ли прием сообщений реализовать как-то попроще?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Про анонимные классы уже все объяснили, но о приеме подробнее:

Обычно в rabbitmq слушателя очереди запускают отдельным потоком, чтобы он висел на этой очереди и обрабатывал все, что приходит:

Инициализация:

```
Connection connection = connectionFactory.newConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null); // объявили очередь
QueueingConsumer queueingConsumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel); // создали слушателя
channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, false, queueingConsumer); // запустили
```

Метод run в Runnable

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = queueingConsumer.nextDelivery();
            if (delivery == null) {
                Thread.sleep(100); // сообщений нет - ждем
            } else {
                handleDelivery(delivery); // обработка
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // цикл прервется если соединение разорвется - это на усмотрение уже
    }
}
```

Обработка полученного сообщения:

```
protected void handleDelivery(QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery) throws IOException {
    try {
        processMsg(delivery.getBody()); // бизнес лоигка
        channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false); // подтверждение приема
    } catch (Exception e) {
        channel.basicReject(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), true); // возвращение в очередь - на усмотрение
    }
}
```

Comment: получается, вы создаете соединение, потом в теле этого анонимного класса Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel), на базе которого создается объект, вы запускаете поток? этот потом работает с задержкой, "прощупывая канал" каждые 100 миллисекунд? если есть сообщение,запускает цикл и обрабатывает его?я верно понимаю?

Comment: @Iga все так, кроме того что здесь нет DefaultConsumer,  в этом примере consumer - QueueingConsumer

Comment: еще несколько вопросов.чем занимается метод, который вы прокомментировали как "бизнес логика"?его идея выделяет красным..
и еще, скажите, где вы берет информацию по методам и классам rabbitmq?на их оф сайте оно скупо все описывается...(

Comment: и еще вопрос. почему вы использовали QueueingConsumer вместо DefaultConsumer?

Comment: @Iga 1. бизнес логика - это обработка полученных байт, реализуйте его так как нужно в вашей программе. 2. в java doc на классах описывается как их лучше применять 3. QueueingConsumer работает в отдельном потоке, а DefaultConsumer в том же потоке что и канал, в итоге первый не блокирует рэббит обработкой сообщений, а второй блокирует

Comment: ааа,то есть processMsg(delivery.getBody());-вы объявили метод, в который передали полученное из метода .getBody() сообщение delivery и ниже я могу его тело прописать сам.
что касается классов я покопался и нашел буквально 10 минут назад сокращение для идеи Ctrl+q после наведения курсора на метод в IDE и мне выводится часть официального  дока по классу и документу). в целом очень многое прояснилось. огромней шее вам спасибо

Answer (score 4):

Такая конструкция называется анонимный класс. Это одновременное объявление наследника класса `DefaultConsumer`, его реализация и вызов конструктора.

Когда вы создаете новый объект, вы пишете так:

```
new Foo(<parameters>);
```

В случае с анонимным классом вы делаете так:

```
new Foo() { 
    // Тело нового класса
}
```

Фактически вы создаете наследника класса `Foo` и одновременно вызываете его конструктор, дополнительно в теле реализуя/переопределяя необходимые методы. То есть такой себе одноразовый класс-наследник.

Можно сделать так в отдельном файле:

```
class MyConsumer extends DefaultConsumer {

   @Override
      public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
          throws IOException {
        String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
      }
}
```

А затем:

```
channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, new MyConsumer());
```

по смыслу было бы аналогично, но в дальнейшем можно ещё создавать объекты `MyConsumer`, в то время как при использовании анонимного класса вы его описали, создали объект и забыли о его описании.

Зачем это, конкретно в вашем примере?
Объект `consumer` в данном случае задает логику, которая должна работать при различный действиях с сообщениями.
Если посмотрите [исходный код](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rabbitmq/client/DefaultConsumer.java) `DefaultConsumer`, то увидите, что метод `handleDelivery` пустой. Исходя из его названия, это обработчик, который вызывается, если сообщение доставлено. В вашем примере для наглядности этот метод переопределяется в одноразовом классе-наследнике, для того, чтобы на консоль вывелась информация о том, что сообщение доставлено, и, собственно, само сообщение. 
В общем случае такие конструкции полезны, ибо можно делать гибкий код. 
Сегодня вам нужно лишь вывести информацию в консоль о доставке сообщения, а завтра вам понадобится переадресовывать сообщение кому-то, или отправлять бабушке только после того, как оно было отправлено дедушке. Тогда вы напишите какой-нибудь `ForwardingConsumer` или `GrandmaConsumer`, в котором будет соответствующая логика.

Comment: а я думаю,что это такое...
то есть используя анонимный класс, мы можем не плодить классы отдельно, а создавать анонимный и в нужный момент переопределять его внутренние методы?

Comment: @Iga, примерно. Если нужно переопределить/дописать 1-2 коротких метода и использовать один раз такой объект, то используют анонимные классы. Только создание и переопределение в один момент происходит. Анонимный, именно потому, что это класс без имени, одноразовый.

Comment: а сколько анонимный класс живет? только время его использования?

Comment: @Iga, учитывая что анонимный класс является одновременно объектом, то он живет пока есть ссылки на него, как и любой другой объект.